# Delete values from dataframe in the fastest possible manner

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with over 5M+ rows. I also have a list of values which I want to delete from the the dataframe. Let's say that my list name is `a` and my dataframe name is `df`. Below is the code I use to check if item in `a` is present in `df`, and then delete it from `df`:

```
 if len(a) > 0:
       for i in tqdm(a):
             indexName = df[ df['id'] == i ].index
             df.drop(indexName , inplace=True)
```

The above code takes 5 minutes. Although it works, I am pretty sure there is a much more efficient method. Please share if you have any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop calls `df.drop` multiple times which is not efficient. You can do it with a single call using [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html).

Consider:

```
values_to_delete = [5, 6, 7]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})
df.drop(df[df['a'].isin(values_to_delete)].index, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Outputs

```
    a
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
7   8
8   9
9  10
```

---

Adapted to your code:

```
df.drop(df[df['id'].isin(tqdm(a))].index , inplace=True)
```

### A faster alternative

(see timings below)

It's possible to filter the dataframe for the values you want instead of dropping the values that you don't want:

```
df = df[~df['id'].isin(tqdm(a))]  # note the ~ which acts as NOT operator
```

---

### Timings

```
from timeit import Timer
import numpy as np

values_to_delete = [5, 6, 7]

def create_df():
    return pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(1, 10, 500000)})

def drop_loop():
    df = create_df()
    for i in values_to_delete:
        indexName = df[df['a'] == i].index
        df.drop(indexName, inplace=True)

def drop_single_call():
    df = create_df()
    df.drop(df[df['a'].isin(values_to_delete)].index, inplace=True)

def filtering():
    df = create_df()
    df[~df['a'].isin(values_to_delete)]


print(min(Timer(drop_loop).repeat(5, 5)))
print(min(Timer(drop_single_call).repeat(5, 5)))
print(min(Timer(filtering).repeat(5, 5)))
```

Outputs

```
1.0248285
0.5842238000000002
0.24234719999999932
```

(Basically) 5 tries for each method (OP's, a drop with a single call and filtering) for a sample dataframe with 500,000 rows. The filtering method is generally faster by 75%.

Comment: Just checked, this takes a couple of milliseconds to complete the task. Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you can add relative speeds using `timeit` or something?

Comment: @Engineero Added